# why am i getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in the advanced for loop?

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, concurrentmodification

Unlike other exception scenarios I've seen, the exception I keep getting happens at the *for loop* I commented below with *//where it goes wrong//*. And in my implementation, the List `partialR` doesn't change while I iterate it, so I am really confused.

```
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return permute(nums, 0, result);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums, int i, List<List<Integer>> result){
        if (i == nums.length){
            return result;
        }
        int num = nums[i];
        List<List<Integer>> partialR = permute(nums, i+1, result);
        System.out.println("partialR"+partialR);
        for (List<Integer> t : partialR){***//where it goes wrong//***
            System.out.println("t"+t);
            for (int j=0; j <= t.size(); j++){
                System.out.println("j="+j);
                List<Integer> subs = insert(t,num,j);
                result.add(subs);
                System.out.println("result"+result);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("result");
        return result;
    }
    public List<Integer> insert(List<Integer> t, int num, int j){
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();       
        if (j == 0){
            temp.add(num);
            temp.addAll(t);
            System.out.println("temp"+temp);
            return temp;
        }else if(j == t.size()){
            temp.addAll(t);
            temp.add(num);
            return temp;
        }
        List<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer> (t.subList(j,t.size()-1));
        List<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer> (t.subList(0,j-1));
        temp.addAll(temp1);
        temp.add(num);
        temp.addAll(temp2);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: *And in my implementation, the List partialR doesn't change while i iterate it*. It may seem that way, but `partialR` references the same list as `result`, which you're clearly modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `result` to `permute`, and it returns `result`.
So when you do this:

> ```
> List<List<Integer>> partialR = permute(nums, i+1, result);
> ```

Now `partialR` points to `result` too.
And then when you iterate over it with `for (List<Integer> t : partialR)`,
you modify `result` when you do `result.add(subs)`.
So in effect, you're modifying `result` while you're iterating over it,
which is not allowed by the *fail-fast* behavior of iterators in Java.
(You can read more about this in the javadoc of [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).)

You could fix this by creating a new `ArrayList` here:

```
List<List<Integer>> partialR = new ArrayList<>(permute(nums, i + 1, result));
```

There are some other mistakes too, unrelated to the concurrent modification.
In `insert`, the range of values to create `temp1` and `temp2` are incorrect.
Corrected and simplified, you can write:

```
List<Integer> temp1 = t.subList(j, t.size());
List<Integer> temp2 = t.subList(0, j);
```